# How do you write (x-1)(x-2)(x-3)...(1) as a gamma function?

Tags: gamma-function

How do you write (x-1)(x-2)(x-3)...(1) as a gamma function?

Assume x is a natural number.

My guess is that it may be (x-1).

I'm looking for an answer in the same format as my guess.

Comment: Is $x$ a real number?

Comment: The Gamma function is a bit shifted with respect to the factorial. $\Gamma(x)=(x-1)!$

Comment: Why would it be shifted?

Comment: The problem is that your question is not well-defined.
Let for example $x=5.2$. Then
$(5.2-1)(5.2-2)(5.2-3)(5.2-4)(5.2-5)$ and you will not get a $1$ as last factor.

Comment: How should it be defined for the last factor to be 1?

Comment: For "How should it be defined for the last factor to be $1$?" you would need $x$ to be a natural number.

Comment: "Simple" is a subjective term. While you might not find this post helpful, others do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Everyone is reading FrustratedSnake's question incorrectly. Since $x$ is a natural number (read the OP completely), the expression in the OP is just $\Gamma (x)=(x-1)!$.

Comment: (Note that the OP did not originally say $x$ is a natural number---consult the edit history.)

Comment: @prets Yes of course that's why the other answer was considering reals in general. But I saw this question later so yeah :)